# Simple example of operator spectral analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm studying on Rudin - Functional Analysis the part related to Banach algebra Bounded/Unbounded operator. Specifically i've studied the part of Banach algebra (where the concept of spectrum is actually mentioned...) probably in the next parts will be some more technical detail... However i had a glance to the chapter i haven't studied yet and i haven't seen a specific example of spectral analysis (the book is quite abstract, like mostly of them focused on the subject). Can you provide me an example of how a spectral analysis is performed?

At present more than the isomorphism between banach algebra and $\mathbb{C}$ (under some condition of course) i haven't seen that much... since i'm looking forward for the stuff i mentioned can you give me an example?

Comment: PS. By the way... please avoid example in finite dimensional space (i.e. matrix)

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for Spectral Theory came from Fourier's separation of variables technique that he invented to solve his heat equation. There was one notable example in particular that Historians say triggered the birth of Spectral Theory. In this example, Fourier was looking at the accuracy of a thermometer and, in particular, the "cooling off" problem for a sphere, where the heat in the spherical end would satisfy
$$
                \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = k\left(\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{2}{x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)
$$
with "boundary conditions" that $v(x,t)$ must remain finite when the distance from the center $x$ tends to $0$, and must satisfy the following conduction condition at the boundary $x=r$ of the sphere:
$$
       \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+hv = 0,\;\;\; x=r,\; t \ge 0.
$$
Both $h$ and $k$ are physical constants.

Using his separation of variables, Fourier obtained solutions of the form
$$
                  u(x,t) = \frac{1}{x}e^{-k\lambda^{2}t}\sin(\lambda x),
$$
where the parameter $\lambda$ may be any solution of the transcendental equation
$$
               \frac{\lambda r}{\tan(\lambda r)}=1-hr.
$$
Fourier easily proves that the equation has an infinity of real solutions $\lambda_n$ tending to $+\infty$. To obtain a solution of the cooling problem with boundary condition, and such that the initial temperature distribution $u(x,0)$ is a given function $f(x)$ at $t=0$, he must write
$$
              xf(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n \sin(\lambda_n x).
$$
Fourier shows that one has the "orthogonality" relations
$$
               \int_{0}^{r}\sin\lambda_n x\sin\lambda_m x dx = 0,\;\;\; m \ne n,
$$
from which he deduces that
$$
               c_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{r}xf(x)\sin\lambda_n x dx}
                          {\int_{0}^{r}\sin^{2}\lambda_n x dx}.
$$
People were already bothered by Fourier's conjecture that the ordinary Fourier series would hold for all reasonable functions. But in this same treatise on Heat Conduction, he further proposed that an even stranger, non-harmonic series of $\sin$ functions could be used to expand all reasonable functions. All of this was so controversial that Fourier's work was not allowed to be published for the next 10-15 years, until Fourier become prominent enough to force its publication.

Fourier's problem can be boiled down to the study of eigenvalue problem for $Lf = -f''$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consisting of all twice continuously differentiable functions on $[0,r]$ for which
$$
                      f(0)=0,\;\;\; f'(r)+\left(h-\frac{1}{r}\right)f(r)=0.
$$
The general solution of $-f''=\lambda^{2} f$ is $A\sin\lambda x+B\cos\lambda x$, and the condition at $x=0$ then gives $B=0$. In order to satisfy the second endpoint condition with a non-zero solution, one must have
$$
     \lambda\cos\lambda r +\left(h-\frac{1}{r}\right)\sin\lambda r = 0.
$$
Fourier recast this equation for the separation parameter $\lambda$ as
$$
                \frac{\lambda r}{\tan(\lambda r)}=1-hr.
$$
In today's language, the eigenvalue is $\sqrt{\lambda}$, and the set of all such eigenvalues is the "spectrum" of the operator. The normalized eigenfunctions $A_n\sin\sqrt{\lambda_n}x$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,r]$, and that allows the type of expansion that Fourier conjectured.

Comment: Though your example is good, i don't get actually pretty well what's the meaning of spectral analysis, the goal is to find eigenvalue? is to to prove that eigenfunction expansion does it exists? Moreover from @Prahlad answer i got that there's no specific way to compute eigenvalue of an operator, so basically it actually depends from "the skill" to use other theorem, is that the way to look at it?

Comment: @Lukkio : The original goal of spectral theory was studying differential operators with the goal of finding the eigenvalues, the eigenfunctions, and showing that the set of eigenfunctions was rich enough to be able to write everything else in the space in terms of these eigenfunctions. This grew into looking at the singularities of the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$ using Complex Analysis. That morphed into the study of algebras of operators and characters, invariant subspaces, and various kinds of representations of operators.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "performing a spectral analysis", but here are some examples that might help you understand the ideas involved:

1. If $T$ is an operator on a finite dimensional Hilbert space, then its spectrum is simply the collection of all eigen-values
2. If $T: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ is the operator
   $$
   T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt
   $$
   Then $T$ is injective, but not surjective (use the fundamental theorem of calculus to check this). Hence, $0$ is a spectral value, but not an eigen-value.
3. If $f \in C[0,1]$ (treated as a Banach algebra with the sup norm), then
   $$
   \sigma(f) = f([0,1])
   $$
   because a function $g\in C[0,1]$ is invertible in $C[0,1]$ if and only if $g(t) \neq 0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$
4. If $x:= (\lambda_n) \in \ell^{\infty}$ (once again, a Banach algebra with the sup-norm and point-wise multiplication), then
   $$
   \sigma(x) = \overline{\{\lambda_n\}}
   $$
   (ie. the closure of the set $\{\lambda_n\} \subset \mathbb{C}$) Try proving this, and you should get the hang of how much of this works.

Comment: That's exactly what i meant, i.e. find eigen values of some operator. However what i don't get (but looking around this website there isn't a a specific way to do that) is how to compute the eigen value of an operator, because as far as i've seen so far is that most of spectral analysis result are of existence and not computation, in linear algebra you've a specific way to perform the analysis but here there isn't. Moreover i've never seen how a spectral analysis of operator is performed.

Comment: Moreover i've seen that you can state for unbounded linear operator if you can perform spectral analysis or not, however looking around the web what i've seen is something like "if you really need to do that... solve the differential equation". So i don't get what kind of "sprint" functional analysis gives compared to "standard analysis" (let's go with that)

Comment: Well, if you want to find the spectrum of a specific operator, it helps to know some qualitative facts about the spectrum in general (for instance, the fact that it is a compact set). Perhaps you should first learn those, and then attempt to find individual spectra - else the latter problem may be too hard.

Comment: I'm more interested in finding some properties that a diagonalized operator probably shows, while a non diagonalized doesn't (i don't know if my comment is related to your one.

Comment: That is a lot more specific than what you have asked in your question - perhaps it is best if you revise your original question or ask a new one to reflect what you actually want.

Comment: I think that if an operator is diagonal it could be expanded in series of eigen function or similar (i speak in such a way because i'm an engineer so i know stuff about fourier analysis, kernel etc) however for me most of this results are given and i don't know how they're given. So i tried to "broaden" my view and look at more abstract results, this is the why of the question, do you still think i should ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be best if you ask a new one - explain your background and what exactly you want to know (it appears you are interested in the spectral theorem for normal operators on a Hilbert space, but I am not sure)